# Need help converting uint8_t array to NSMutableData

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, boost, firebreath

I am trying to port some objective-c code (mac) to c++ code (win). However, I have a problem. On the mac my data comes in as a NSMutableData object and on windows it comes in as a uint8_t array. I need to convert my uint8_t data to the same type of data that is inside NSMutableData. Help!

```
//on the mac
foo(NSMutableData* received)
{
   void* data = malloc([received length]);
   memcpy(data, [received mutableBytes], [received length]);

   bar(data);
}

//on windows
foo(const boost::shared_array<uint8_t>& received)
{
   void* data = ... //magic needs to happen here 

   bar(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does bar expect to get a block of memory it will own and free itself as your Mac example indicates?

```
void *data = malloc(received_size); //shared_array can't give you the size info
memcpy(data,received.get(),received_length);
bar(data);
```

If bar doesn't take ownership of the memory then you can just pass the data to it without making a copy:

```
void *data = static_cast<void*>(received.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

uh; there is no such thing as a NSMutableData object on windows, so you're going to have to be more specific about what format you need it in eventually.

According to apple docs NSMutableData is a buffer of byte data; well, that's what a uint8_t array is as well.  If they both just assume an array of that data then you can just pass the pointer to the block.

In actuality, it would make much more sense to convert a NSMutableData object to a uint8_t pointer than the other way around, since likely that's what you have inside the MutableData anyway.

Hope that helps